# Custom code in C# before synching database of the client with Sql server Database

Tags: microsoft-sync-framework

I am using Microsoft Synch Service Framework 4.0 for synching Sql server Database tables with SqlLite Database on the Ipad side.

I want to customize the C# code. The client will be sending me some parameters e.g. SessionId with the synch services. Depending on the parameters, the code will decide whether to continue with the synching or not. Now, the below code is for initializing the synch service. Where can I put the custom code for processing the parameters. Basically,

If ( Session Id already exists)
          // Continue with synching

else
{
          Do not continue with synching
}

I believe this is possible using Interceptors: Request, Response OR Conflict Interceptors.
Could anyone provide an example so that I can write business logic before synching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you should be writing a Request Interceptor.

here's a quick/basic [intro](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rameshvanaparthy2/archive/2011/01/06/sync-upload-request-intercptor-for-business-logic-implementation-and-validation.aspx) on how to write one.

Comment: Yes, Request Interceptor is right. Client is sending me "Server_Code" through header. In Request Interceptor, I am checking the following :                                                                    if (serverCode == "DEV")
{
     foreach (IOfflineEntity entity in context.IncomingChanges)
     {
              context.RejectChange(entity, "Invalid Server");
     }

}                                                                      The thing is I am getting "0" count in Incoming changes. Is there any other way( without IOffine) to check validation

Answer (score 0):

Well, I faced some problem while using Interceptors when downloading changes from server.
Client is sending me "Server_Code" through header.

```
if (serverCode == "DEV") 
{ 
     foreach (IOfflineEntity entity in context.IncomingChanges) 
     { 
        context.RejectChange(entity, "Invalid Server"); 
     } 
}
```

When client is downloading changes from server, I get IncomingChanges value = 0. Thus I cannot reject changes.

How about using filters for sync.  i.e. Sync will happen based on the parameters sent by the client.
If client sends SessionId, then sync will happen only for that particular SessionId.

Any ideas?